# Need help to display an image in a Google Forms Quiz created using Apps Script from a Google Sheet. Image link is in the Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

newby here - be gentle.

I am trying to create a multiple choice Google Forms "Quiz" driven by a Google Apps Script and data in a Google Sheet.  One column in the Google Sheet has the URL of an image stored in my Google Photos which I would like to display at the beginning of a multiple choice question.

Here is what I would like the quiz to look like.  I created this with a static link to the image which works fine. But I'd like this to be driven by a cell in the sheet.

```
var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
form.addImageItem().setImage(img);
```

[Image of Quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qubrI.jpg)

Link to the google sheet is here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p3wtrouEaBXwLkDYPdzf7-eR_oLWYaiXeAZODIDVAfI/edit?usp=sharing

This code generates a Exception: Blob object must have an image content type for this operation.
popForm @ Code.gs:31

I have tried various approaches but I think I'm confused about what a blob is, file ID versus URL and what it might mean if the image is stored in a folder on my Google Drive or in my Google Pics versus a public image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function popForm() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var numberRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();

  // Read the sheet data into arrays. 

  var myOptions = sheet.getRange(1,1,numberRows,3).getValues();  //Array for the multiple choice options 
  var myImage = sheet.getRange(1,4,numberRows,1).getValues();  //Image URL in column 4 (D)
 
  Logger.log(myOptions);
  Logger.log(myImage);

  // Create the form as a quiz.

  var form = FormApp.create('test quiz 4');
  form.setIsQuiz(true);

  // Write out each multiple choice question to the form.

  for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){

    form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle('Which one is this?');
    Logger.log('IMAGE = ' + myImage[i][0]);


    var img = (UrlFetchApp.fetch(myImage[i][0]));
    var blob = img.getBlob();
    form.addImageItem().setImage(blob);


      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle("What is this thing?")

      .setPoints(1)

      .setChoices([

        addItem.createChoice(myOptions[i][0],true),
        addItem.createChoice(myOptions[i][1]),
        addItem.createChoice(myOptions[i][2]),


      ]);
  }

}
```

Comment: In your situation, the images are required to be publicly shared. I'm worried that your images are not publicly shared. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike - is there a way to do this if the files are located in my google drive?  I can probably find a place to store the images in a publicly accessible location if this becomes necessary.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your new question of `is there a way to do this if the files are located in my google drive?`, it's yes. Because from your replying, I'm not sure about the relationship between your current Spreadsheet and `the files are located in my google drive`, I cannot propose the modified script. But, you can use the image files on your Google Drive.